If YouTube Link in Excerpt use Featured Image as Video using Excerpt Link in Text Else Get Featured Image
I Currently Using Custom Excerpts Where I Allow Tags  for YouTube Videos as Feature Videos, Whereas when I Insert a Featured Image the video is also displayed. I require one featured Image or Video from the Excerpt.
Both Functions are separate sets. (I Need Help in the Condition: Display Feature Image when the YouTube Video Link does not exist in the Excerpt or else display only Video from the excerpt.)
Featured Image

// Meta Attributes
$img_by_code = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'large');
$img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'large');
$img_id  = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());
$alt_text = get_post_meta($img_id , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
$image_title = get_the_title($img_id);
$caption = wp_get_attachment_caption($img_id); 

Image Display
   
//in img tag
echo $img_url;

Custom Excerpt Function.php

//Custom Excerpt Function.php
function customexcerpt($text) {
    $raw_excerpt = $text;

    if ( '' == $text ) {
        //Retrieve the post content. 
        $text = get_the_content('');
     
        //Delete all shortcode tags from the content. 
        $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
     
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
         
        $allowed_tags = ',,'; // Add comma separated tags that should be displayed in the excerpt.
        $text = strip_tags($text, $allowed_tags);
         
        $excerpt_word_count = 55; // Ccustom excerpt work count.
        $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count); 
         
        $excerpt_end = '.....'; // Modify this if you want to change the excerpt_more tag.
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end);
         
        $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        if ( count($words) > $excerpt_length ) {
            array_pop($words);
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
            $text = $text . $excerpt_more;
        } else {
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
        }
    }

    return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'customexcerpt');


Excerpt Display the Video:
echo customexcerpt('');
